# How to remove html tags from string without removing specific tags in Js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following js string

```
var test = "<p>test</p> FOLER.PRODUCTS<12345><level-2>";
```

Now I am using the following approach to strip html tags from above string because my service doesn't accept html tags

```
var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");tmp.innerHTML = test;
console.log(tmp.textContent);
```

output :

```
test FOLER.PRODUCTS<12345>
```

Desired output :

```
test FOLER.PRODUCTS<12345><level-2>
```

But above approach removes my custom tag which are having text between **<>**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you please show us your desired output

Comment: use innerHTML instead of textContent

Answer (score 2):

use html encoding

```
 var test = "<p>test</p> FOLER.PRODUCTS<12345>&lt;level-2&gt;";
```

Check this link too https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/

Answer (score -1):

This should help you to be able to strip html tags in the javascript

```
   var test = "<p>test</p> FOLER.PRODUCTS<12345><level-2>";    
   var StrippedString = test.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

You can modify it to suit your needs